# A better way to get show a view controller after tapping selection from Google Places

Tags: swift, google-places-api

I'm following a tutorial to use Google Places into my app and I noticed that after clicking on a filtered result the Google Places View Controller gets dismissed and shows the previous screen that called Google Places. I am not sure how to tweak it so that after the user taps on a result it goes straight to another controller. Right now I have it where after the results is tapped, the Google Places controller is dismissed and I call a `present` to bring up the other controller. How do I go to the next controller after the user taps on the result without going back to the controller that called Google Places?

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlaces

class TravelerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func autocompleteClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        autocompleteController.delegate = self
        present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
}

extension TravelerViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

    // Handle the user's selection.
    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        print("Place name: \(place.name)")
        print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress)")
        print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TravelerResults")

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
        // TODO: handle the error.
        print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
    }

    // User canceled the operation.
    func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
    func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make separate function for open View Controller.

```
@objc func openVC() {
    let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TravelerResults")
    self.present(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Call this function in AutoComplete.

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        print("Place name: \(place.name)")
        print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress)")
        print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        openVC()

    }
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't what I am looking for. This is the same as the code posted above where the controller and presenting the view controller is just put into a function and called. If the question is not clear let me know.

Comment: "I am not sure how to tweak it so that after the user taps on a result it goes straight to another controller. Right now I have it where after the results is tapped, the Google Places controller is dismissed and I call a present to bring up the other controller. " After selection of place, you want to present new controller? Right?

Comment: Yeah. So instead of having to call the dismiss function I want it to go to another view controller. Though, without the dismiss call the Google Places View Controller will just hang.

Comment: @LampPost i test this code first on my xcode, its work fine. Please you implement the code.

Comment: The answer is just some of my code that's called in a function so it's the same thing...

Comment: @LampPost I again test the code its open second Viewcontroller, basically you miss the sequence of code.

Comment: @LampPost you first call dismiss then call present which is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162764/discussion-between-lamppost-and-khawar-islam).